# How to add my new library package to Yocto Extensible SDK (eSDK)?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I get it that Yocto eSDK is snapshot of pre-configured OpenEmbedded build system. But I want to verify that the custom library that I add as a new meta layer (say, meta-foo layer) becomes a part of eSDK. So, that the user applications may include the header files of this custom library, link against the *.a of this custom library **and** that the user applications may  link **in runtime** against shared objects of this custom library.

So, is it enough to define in the recipe of this custom library just:

```
RPROVIDES = "custom_lib1.so custom_lib2.so ..."
```

... to tell bitbake to copy those `*.so` libraries to the RootFS?

And how to ensure that the header files of this custom library are copied to the appropriate place, say, `/usr/include`?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, [RPROVIDES](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-RPROVIDES) is used for deliver package dependency, thus You need provide here recipe name.

Firstly You need to create recipe with will use *do_install* function into deliver needed binaries to *${D}${includedir}/*. Then add created package (recipe) as *RDEPENDS* to [nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb) recipe.

Comment: I don't think that `nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb` needs to be changed at all. For example, openssl headers are present in Yocto eSDK, but openssl is not mentioned in `nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host.bb` file. So, there must be some other way to do it...